# How do you escape a dash in Jython/Websphere?

Tags: python, websphere, jython, websphere-7, wsadmin

I have a Jython script that is used to set up a JDBC datasource on a Websphere 7.0 server. I need to set several properties on that datasource. I am using this code, which **works**, unless `value` is `'-'`.

```
def setCustomProperty(datasource, name, value):
    parms = ['-propertyName', name, '-propertyValue', value]
    AdminTask.setResourceProperty(datasource, parms)
```

I need to set the `dateSeparator` property on my datasource to just that - a dash. When I run this script with `setCustomProperty(ds, 'dateSeparator', '-')` I get an exception that says, "Invalid property: ". I figured out that it thinks that the dash means that another parameter/argument pair is expected.

Is there any way to get AdminTask to accept a dash?

NOTE: I can't set it via AdminConfig because I cannot find a way to get the id of the right property (I have multiple datasources).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that uses `AdminConfig` so that you can set the property value to the dash `-`. The solution accounts for multiple data sources, finding the correct one by specifying the appropriate scope (i.e. the server, but this could be modified if your datasource exists within a different scope) and then finding the datasource by name. The solution also accounts for modifying the existing "dateSeparator" property if it exists, or it creates it if it doesn't.

The code doesn't look terribly elegant, but I think it should solve your problem :

```
def setDataSourceProperty(cell, node, server, ds, propName, propVal) :
  scopes = AdminConfig.getid("/Cell:%s/Node:%s/Server:%s/" % (cell, node, server)).splitlines()
  datasources = AdminConfig.list("DataSource", scopes[0]).splitlines()
  for datasource in datasources :
    if AdminConfig.showAttribute(datasource, "name") == ds :
      propertySet = AdminConfig.list("J2EEResourcePropertySet", datasource).splitlines()
      customProp = [["name", propName], ["value", propVal]]
      for property in AdminConfig.list("J2EEResourceProperty", propertySet[0]).splitlines() :
        if AdminConfig.showAttribute(property, "name") == propName :
          AdminConfig.modify(property, customProp)
          return
      AdminConfig.create("J2EEResourceProperty", propertySet[0], customProp)

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
  setDataSourceProperty("myCell01", "myNode01", "myServer", "myDataSource", "dateSeparator", "-")
  AdminConfig.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the Management [Console preferences settings](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/ucon_rpref.html). You can do what you are attempting now and you should get to see the Jython equivalent that the Management Console is creating for its own use. Then just copy it.

Comment: It uses an AdminConfig command to set it. The problem is that I cannot guarantee that I'll be able to getid() that property across multiple platforms. I can list them, but on Linux until a save() is performed, I can't see properties already created. Do you know how to access a custom property for a specific datasource?

Comment: Ah, how disappointing. To be honest, I would modify the XML files. Just set the value to some dummy value, and search & replace the configuration files. Very ugly, but gets the job done with couple commands.

Answer (score 0):

@Schemetrical solution worked for me. Just giving another example with jvm args.
Not  commenting on the actual answer because I don't have enough reputation.

```
server_name = 'server1'
AdminTask.setGenericJVMArguments('[ -serverName %s -genericJvmArguments "-agentlib:getClasses" ]' % (server_name))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using a String instead of an array to pass the parameters using double quotes to surround the values starting with a dash sign

Example:

```
AdminTask.setVariable('-variableName JDK_PARAMS -variableValue "-Xlp -Xscm250M" -variableDescription "-Yes -I -can -now -use -dashes -everywhere :-)" -scope Cell=MyCell')
```